# Add style dynamically not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, styles

sorry for my english.
i want to hide a div in my site. i am using this code

```
  $('ul .tab li').attr("style", "display: none");
```

This work on all web browsers. but when i look in to this by my ipad. there is error present. After some google search i found that attr is not supported some ipad browsers. Then
i can only use javascript for styling my website dynamically. when i use this code i got an error that

```
  document.querySelectorAll('ul .tab li').style.display = "none";
  document.querySelectorAll('ul .tab li li').style.display = "block";
```

error is

```
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined
```

if anyone know about this please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Try

`$('ul .tab li').css("display", "none");`

Also,

is `lib` a class assigned to the `ul` element? In which case, the right way to do it is

`$('ul.tab li').css("display", "none");`

Remove the space between the `ul` and `.tab`

UPDATE:

`querySelectorAll` returns an `Array`. That is why you can not directly use `.style` attribute. You will have to loop through that array to apply that style to the selected elements.

Comment: jQuery's `.css()` is the right way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Jquery [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
  $('ul .tab li').css("display", "none");
   AND
  $('ul .tab li').css("display", "block");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('ul .tab li');
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].style.display = 'block'; //Or none
}
```

[Here is a simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/bNa7S/1/)

Comment: Might as well use jQuery if the OP already has it in the page.

Comment: But as @deepu suggested to use javascript as jQuery don't work on few ipad versions.

Comment: `.attr()` is  NOT how you should be setting `.style` properties in any browser/device.  jQuery `.css()` works just fine for setting style properties (on all iPads) as that is what its purpose is.  The OP's problem was a misuse of `.attr()` not a jQuery problem with iPad.

Answer (score 0):

**try this pure javascript:**

```
var list=document.getElementsByTagName("UL")[0];
var list1=list.getElementsByClassName('tab'); 
list1.getElementsByTagName("LI")[0].style.display = "none";
```

Comment: Might as well use jQuery if the OP already has it in the page.

Answer (score 0):

you could just use

```
$('ul .tab li').hide();
```